# C++ segmentation fault in std::string function

Tags: c++, string, gdb, segmentation-fault, allocator

I'm developing an algorithm based on Skyline queries using C++, using a RTree for storing my data. The algorithm works fine if I process up to 5 points then if I try 6 points it gives a segmentation fault.
Using gdb I have discovered that the problem is here:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string (
    this=0x7fffffffd7c0, __str=
    <error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffe8>)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-4.7.2-20120921/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:175
175           __str.get_allocator())
```

Can anybody help me to understand where the error is or ar

Comment: You have a bug in your code. If you want a more specific answer, post the relevant code.

Comment: Mitch the code is quite long to post, more over is part of my final year project and my university might interpret that as cheating. Anyway I can post maybe a part of it

Comment: Try using Valgrind....

Comment: @clapclash: We are incapable of clairvoyance. We cannot know what your code is going just from a random error. We cannot magically intuit where some kind of problem may have occurred. If you want our help, you need to show us enough of the code that the problem is reproduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mitch Wheat already suggested this in a comment, but I think it is in fact the best answer for your problem, so:

Use valgrind.

Valgrind is a tool (or rather, a set of tools) for which the default mode of operation is to run your program and check for memory errors, such as leaks, buffer overruns, uninitialized reads, and more.

Literally all you need to do is to build your program, preferably with the `-g` option to make it easier to debug, and then run it like `valgrind my-prog args...`.  Valgrind will then print out detailed error reports with stack traces when something bad is going on.  Your problem here will likely be found without ever needing to use a regular debugger, nor have us guess at the problem (if this were my own problem, I'd use valgrind too).

Comment: "*Literally all you need to do is to build your program*" You also have to be running it on Linux (or MacOSX). Which is not always a thing you can do.

Comment: @NicolBolas: True, but the OP is using `GDB`.  I'd say it's a safe bet that this code is running under a *nix OS.

Comment: @EdS. not really since MinGW comes with GDB.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I guess, but given that the OP mentions `/usr/src/debug/gcc-4.7.2-20120921/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:175`...I think valgrind is a pretty safe bet.

Comment: @Rapptz: True... still a safe bet.  Far more people using it on *nix than there are MinGW users on Windows.  Yeah, and that ^ above.

Answer (score 1):

Given only that, my best guess is that you're trying to create a string using invalid source data, possibly a char pointer that's unitialized or that's pointing to a string that's already been freed